# How can i setup eBay trading api with production account?

Tags: ebay-api

I have merchant account in eBay (production) and developer account (Sandbox).
All i need is working on Sandbox, but how can i relate that code with production account.

```
$this->service = new Services\TradingService(array(
        'apiVersion' => '911',
        'siteId' => 0,
        'appId' => '',
        'sandbox' => false,
        'certId' => '',
        'devId' => '',
            //'debug' => true
    ));

How can i find appId, certId and devId in production account?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the eBay developer site and request a set of production keys.

If you have it working with sandbox keys you should me able to just swap in your production keys.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Everithing is working on Sandbox. :)